# One Datepicker value automatically in second datepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, datepicker, momentjs

I have a form having two fields of Calendar/Datepicker..

Field No.1

```
    <div class="input-group date" id="gnd_institutiondate">
                          <input id="gnd_institutiondate_val" class="form-control" placeholder="DD-MM-YYYY" data-date-format="DD-MM-YYYY" data-inputmask="'mask': '99-99-9999'" required="" name="gnd_institutiondate" type="text">
                          <span class="input-group-addon">
                             <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                          </span>
                      </div>
<input id="gnd_institutiondate_val" class="form-control" placeholder="DD-MM-YYYY" data-date-format="DD-MM-YYYY" data-inputmask="'mask': '99-99-9999'" required="" name="gnd_institutiondate" type="text">
```

Field No.2

```
 <div class="input-group date" id="gnd_courtregisterdate">
                          <input id="gnd_courtregisterdate_val" class="form-control" placeholder="DD-MM-YYYY" data-date-format="DD-MM-YYYY" data-inputmask="'mask': '99-99-9999'" required="" name="gnd_courtregisterdate" type="text">
                          <span class="input-group-addon">
                             <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                          </span>
                      </div>
```

I want that when I select a date from Field No.1(Calendar/Datepicker) then its automatically filled in Field No.2(Calendar/Datepicker).

(From is using Moment.js , DataTables, Select2, JQuery (javascript libraries) & UI framework is bootstrap.)

I want to link two date pickers so that when a date is selected in one date picker, the second date picker automatically takes the same date.

Please suggest a javascript code for me or any chrome extension... I am new in coding...

The following code is working with another same fields.

```
setTimeout(function() {
    var institutionNoInput = document.getElementById("gnd_institutionno");
    var courtRegisterNoInput = document.getElementById("gnd_courtregisterno");

    institutionNoInput.addEventListener("input", function() {
        courtRegisterNoInput.value = institutionNoInput.value;
    });
}, 1000); // You can adjust the timeout value (in milliseconds) as needed
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
 document.getElementById('date1').addEventListener('change',(e) => {
   document.getElementById('date2').value=e.target.value
 })
```

- intead of 'input' put 'change' and remove the `setTimeout` function
- type of the input should be date not text

Comment: Sir coding is built-in in web and i dont have access to change coding.  i just want to use auto fill fields option on a web form..